# flash[:notice] not working in Rails 4 after edit/create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can get flash messaging to work after create and destroy when they are redirected to root_path but cannot get it to work when update redirects to show.html.erb for some reason. What do you think is the problem? My Quote model has 4 columns(id, category, author and quotetext)

My show view

```
<% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="notice">
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% @category.each do |quote| %>
<div>
<p><strong> <%= quote.category %></strong></p>
<p><em><%= quote.author %></em></p>
<p> <%= quote.text %> </p>
<hr>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Home', quotes_path %>
```

My controller:

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /quotes
  # GET /quotes.json
  def index
    @quotes = Quote.sorted
  end

  # GET /quotes/1
  # GET /quotes/1.json
  def show
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /quotes/new
  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
    #apparently this doesn't really do anything but good to specify
  end

  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
      flash[:notice] = "Quote #{@quote.pkey} created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  # GET /quotes/1/edit
  def edit
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1.json
  def update
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    if @quote.update_attributes(quote_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Quote #{@quote.pkey} updated!"
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @quote.id)
    else 
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  # DELETE /quotes/1
  # DELETE /quotes/1.json
  def destroy
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Quote #{@quote.pkey} deleted!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def set_quote
      @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    end

    def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:category, :author, :quotetext)
    end
end
```

my index view

```
<div class='jumbotron'>
<h1>Root Index Page</h1>
</div>


<%= render 'shared/nav' %>

<div class="quotes index">

<%= render 'flash' %>

<table class="listing">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Pkey</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Quote Text </th>
  </tr>
  <% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=quote.pkey %></td>
    <td><%=quote.category %></td>
    <td><%=quote.author %></td>
    <td><%=quote.text %></td>
    <td class="actions">
    <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => quote.id}) %>
    <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => quote.id}) %>
    <%= link_to quote_path(quote.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete Quote ##{quote.id}?"} do %><span class=edit>Delete</span><% end %>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

</div>
```

my edit view

```
<h1>Edit Existing Quote <%=@quote.pkey%> </h1>

<%= form_for(@quote) do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :author %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :quotetext %>
  </p>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update quote" %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @quote %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', quotes_path %>
```

flash partial

```
<% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="notice">
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flash.keep is a method applied to flash an the params should be passed as argument, not array:

```
flash.keep(:notice)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

And the source code:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-keep

Comment: thank you, and my bad, that was not supposed to be in there .. it still doesn't work when i just do flash[:notice] ... any ideaS??

Comment: change view to <%= if flash[:notice] %>

Comment: And show me the partial 'flash'.  And where are you rendering the flash notice in the edit?